# A bash script that would watch 2 processes and when one dies kill the other

Tags: bash, vim

I have an issue with the vim plugin slimv where it will start a separate process for a backend server and then I have to manually kill it after I close vim.

I was wondering if there you could make a script that would watch both processes and then when vim closes it would kill the other one?

Is the possible?
If it is... How would you make it?

Comment: Maybe you could use a mapping to run a shell command whenever you quit (ie override `:q` or `ZZ`).  But... It would probably be better to fix the issue that causes the problem to begin with!

Comment: If you know the PID of the server and client, all you need is `wait $clientpid; kill $serverpid`

Comment: It would not be unreasonable to report this as a bug to the plugin author; if it starts the server, it should stop it as well.

Comment: @chepner It's not really a bug. Since it starts up as a process not attached to vim vim has no control over it. we can't seem to find a  way to kill the process when vim quits.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that from within Vim, hooking into the `VimLeave` event:

```
:autocmd VimLeave * call system('killall backend-process')
```